# Cannot override default cache-control of primefaces resources

Tags: jsf, primefaces, cache-control, open-liberty

I am developing an application in Jakarta EE, Primefaces 12 and OpenLiberty. When I load the app, the primefaces resources (js and css files), mainly containing the URL as "jakarta.faces.resources" are loaded with a Cache-Control : max-age=604800.

Due to security reasons, I need to make my Cache-Control as "no-store" on load. But however hard I try to set this header, it just overrides with the max-age part all the time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would check this out: https://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/CacheControlFilter

You can control any resources and set their cache control. I use this..

```xml
    <!-- No Cache Filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

**Important notice:** this filter automatically skips Faces resources, such as the ones served by <h:outputScript>, <h:outputStylesheet>, @ResourceDependency, etc. Their cache-related headers are namely already controlled by the ResourceHandler implementation. In Mojarra and MyFaces, the default expiration time is 1 week (604800000 milliseconds), which can be configured by a web.xml context parameter with the following name and a value in milliseconds, e.g. 3628800000 for 6 weeks:

**Mojarra:** com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge

**MyFaces:** org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_MAX_TIME_EXPIRES

It would not make sense to control their cache-related headers with this filter as they would be overridden anyway.

Comment: I have tried this already, it doesn't help. The initial load is always the default one. It changes on the second load and hence gives me a 304 status and doesn't load anything.

Comment: I just edited my answer it is right from the OmniFaces page on Max Age.

Comment: so no matter what I try it would override it correct?

Comment: ITs what it sounds like unless you tweak the Mojarra or MyFaces MaxAge proeprty but that sets it for all resources.